# (initramfs) /cow format specified as aufs and no support found

Tags: boot, kernel, realtime

I added a Real-Time patch to my existing Ubuntu 14.04 kernel to make it soft RT Linux. I've the steps for RT Linux here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu

```
Ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu 4.9.115-rt93 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Aug 22 18:27:09 IST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Next, I wanted to create an ISO file of this RT Ubuntu OS so that I could boot it on a different system. I used Pinguy builder tool to create the ISO. https://www.ostechnix.com/pinguy-builder-build-custom-ubuntu-os/

However, when I try to boot this ISO on a different system, it gets stuck in initramfs and throws the following error

```
(initramfs) /cow format specified as aufs and no support found.
```

I so far didn't find any solution online, can someone assist me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Press Enter and after that Ctrl + D, it made the magic in my case with a KDE neon 15.5 Live CD I created.